# How can I launch web browser automatically with given window size and url

Tags: linux, browser, launcher

In linux, is it possible to launch web browser with given window size and url using terminal console or some kind of script (e.g., shell)?

What I want to do is to test the web streaming server to see how many clients can video-stream from the server and manually launch firefox is quite annoying task.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox supports [command-line arguments to specify URL, height and width](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments). For example:

```
firefox -height 600 -width 800 "example.com"
```

Depending on your setup, that might actually open in new tabs. Use `-new-window "example.com"` to force a new window.

Do note that these windows will actually launch under a single process, reusing one if FF is already open. Apparently, **setting the size will not work unless you're starting a new process** (see the comments). You must specify `-no-remote` in order to launch multiple independent processes, and each must use a different profile, which you can specify with `-p "profilename"`. Profiles must be created before use.

For example, if you were to do this in a loop (bash):

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    firefox -no-remote -createprofile testprofile$i
    firefox -no-remote -p testprofile$i -height 600 -width 800 "example.com"&
done
```

(The `&` is at the end to [run it in the backround](https://superuser.com/a/152695/117590), i.e. don't wait for it to close.)

Comment: Question is tagged Linux but yes dimension parameters work despite not being listed by `firefox --help`

Comment: @justbrowsing Yea, I just noticed I had `.exe` on the end. Force of habit. The rest should be applicable to Linux, AFAIK.

Comment: I tried the following commands and the dimension param looks like not applied: firefox -height 300 -width 200 -new-window  "google"

Comment: also, adding -no-remote -createprofile "test1" to the argument does not work..., which setup am I missing?

Comment: @jaeyong WorksForMe (Kubuntu, Firefox 23.0, what are you running?). You have to create profiles independently of using them; I'll amend the answer to include that.

Comment: `-height` and `-width` seems to work only if firefox isn't already running. `-new-window` does open in a new window, but if FF is running, it uses the dimensions of the previous window. Running FF 22 on ubuntu 12.04.2 with Unity

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. Is this what you are asking?

`firefox --no-remote -P testing http://my-url`

- You can just launch Firefox with `firefox` command
- `--no-remote` tells it to launch a new instance
- `-P testing` tells it to use a profile you named *testing*
- *URL* opens instance with given URL

As far as the window size requirement, most Window Managers will remember the previous size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I can't advise on sizing the browser, but you can launch a firefox instance by simply typing

```
firefox "url"
```

From a command line.

So if you want to launch, for example, 10 instances you could write a 1 liner to launch multiple tabs to the same url :

```
for each in `seq 1 10`; do firefox ; done
```

I suspect that there are better ways of performance testing the site which don't require a browser, but I'm not an expert when it comes to streaming.   WGET and CURL provide command line functionality for getting web pages and may provide a more objective result (I'm guessing you are not wanting to benchmark the browser, and a GUI has a much higher overhead)

Comment: Yes, I don't want to impose anykind of GUI overhead. But, still want to stress the server by video streaming. Any idea?

Comment: You would need to advise how you are doing the streaming, or replace firefox with a command line stream capturing client.  (Maybe VLC can help you by at least lowering the GUI overhead compared with a browser, or you could try, or use mencoder and copy the stream rather then convert it ?)

Comment: Oh, right. VLC or menucoder may help! thanks. I didn't think in that view :)