# Can I run two ongoing programs in one terminal?

Tags: terminal, process, node.js

I'm developing a nodejs app with the following npm tasks:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
  "develop": "npm start && npm run watch",
  "build": "webpack --progress",
  "start": "node server.js"
}
```

and I'd like to run two ongoing processes run within one command in one terminal, which is `npm run develop` (it'll run `node server.js` and `webpack --progress --watch`.

My question is, can I do that? If I can, how logs from those two processes will be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. If you have two programs namely prog1 and prog2 then try this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 prog1 2> .errorprog1.log & prog2 2> .errorprog2.log &
```

This will redirect error to separate logs.

You can also try this:

```
prog1 &
prog2 &
```

I have found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script), which contains lots of useful tips that will be beneficial for you. Please go through it.

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was any help to you, so that other can find this thread easily.  Thank you.

Comment: **&** is working in this example as a function of a command separator.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a command in the background by simply using `&` to fork it. So

`$ node server.js &
 $ webpack --progress --watch &`

The output of the two processes will be mixed in terminal, which can be confusing so you can log them to file

`$ node server.js | tee log1 &
 $ webpack --progress --watch | tee log2 &`

Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/152688/why-run-a-linux-shell-command-with) for more details about forking.